How Does Twistor Theory Solve Penrose's Concerns About Computability in Physics?
Roger Penrose believes (for reasons having to do with philosophy of mind and Godel's theorem) that fundamental physics must involve some aspect that is noncomputable (and not merely in the sense that almost all real numbers are noncomputable) and that Twistor Theory (a geometric theory he created to reconcile general relativity with quantum mechanics and which he says also resolves the measurement problem in quantum mechanics) allows this. My question is, how does Twistor Theory give rise to noncomputability?

I was not aware that Penrose believes that twistors are special in this respect. Do you have any reference for this? By the way, almost all mathematics gives rise to noncomputability.

Penrose has stated that he believes the reconciliation of quantum theory with relativity will involve noncomputable physics. He has also stated that twistor theory is aimed at reconciling the two. I infer from this that he believes twistors would be more amenable to this than existing physics. Relativity and quantum mechanics (with unitary evolution) are both fully computable - one can algorithmically calculate the evolution of a system under either theory with arbitrarily small timesteps.

https://www.edge.org/conversation/roger_penrose-chapter-14-consciousness-involves-noncomputable-ingredients
"My main technical interest is in twistor theory — a radical approach to space and time — and, in particular, how to fit it in with Einstein's general relativity. There's a major problem there, in which some progress was made a few years ago, and I feel fairly excited about it. It's ultimately aimed at finding the appropriate union between general relativity and quantum theory."

"I argue that we shall need to find some noncomputational physical process if we're ever to explain the effects of consciousness. But I don't see it in any existing theory. It seems to me that the only place where noncomputability can possibly enter is in what is called "quantum measurement." But we need a new theory of quantum measurement. It must be a noncomputable new theory. There is scope for this, if the new theory involves changes in the very structure of quantum theory, of the kind that could arise when it's appropriately united with general relativity."

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. Please edit your question to incorporate the useful information in your comments.
